# printing arrays and enums in relation to each other C

Tags: arrays, c, function, printing, enums

I am trying to print the enums `Months` in relation to the `Numbers` array. I am trying to format the print function with the relation

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   Numbers[12] = {3,4,5,1,2,7,8,9,3,4,7,8};
   enum Months {Jan, Feb, March, April, May, June, July, August, September, October, November, December};            
   for(int i = 0; i> 12; i ++){
          printf("Month: %d Number: %d", Months[i], Numbers[i]);   

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Jan:  3
Feb:  4
March: 5
April: 1
May: 2
June: 7
July: 8
August: 9
September: 3 
October: 4 
November: 7
December: 8
```

Comment: Enums are not strings. You need to have an array of strings instead or a function that converts an enum value to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the array must be defined with a data type. I assume it is integer.

Another major issue is that the enums are not strings. They are used to set meaningful names for constants such as `enum {OPTION1, OPTION2, OPTION3}` to reduce the usage of magical numbers. Thus, we need to use a character array to store the name of the months.

Lastly, a semantic issue is `i > 12` in the loop – this won't let the loop be executed. Instead, the condition should be `i < 12`.

The polished code should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 32

int main() {
    int Numbers[12] = {3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 7, 8};
    char Months[][MAX_LEN] = {"Jan",       "Feb",     "March",    "April",
                              "May",       "June",    "July",     "August",
                              "September", "October", "November", "December"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
        printf("%s: %d\n", Months[i], Numbers[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

So you get the correct output:

```
rohanbari@genesis:~/stack$ ./a.out
Jan: 3
Feb: 4
March: 5
April: 1
May: 2
June: 7
July: 8
August: 9
September: 3
October: 4
November: 7
December: 8
```